# What are some less known pairs of binary operators on Integers are distributive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, integers, binary-operations

The operations of addition(+) and multiplication(*) as ordinarily defined on integers are distributive.
$$a*(b+c) = a*b + a*c $$
There are a lot of other sets on which operations defined on them are distributive (set intersection distributes over union).

I am interested in any other less known pair of operations which are defined on integers that have distributive property.

Comment: There's a few at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Other_examples

Comment: Thanks for the link. There is only one entry regarding integers which states that GCD is distributive over LCM. The concept of GCD and LCM already use the notion of multiplication and division. I was looking for something that is not related to common notion of addition and multiplication.